# Bundler 1.12.0 cannot be run as a user with no $HOME directory

Tags: bash, bundler

With the latest version of `bundler`, I keep getting errors such as:

```
STDOUT: There was an error while trying to write to /home/user1/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47. 
It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
```

I'm running `sudo su - user2 bundle install synapse`, where `user2` has no HOME directory.  I'm trying to install Airbnb Smartstack using Chef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the latest version of Bundler insists on writing the new index cache files to `$HOME/.bundle`.  This means that commands such as:

```
sudo su - homelessuser bundle install synapse
```

...fail when they try to write to the `$HOME/.bundle` of the user that called `sudo ...`.

As a workaround, I'm pinning my bundler version to 1.11.2 for now.

**Note** The GitHub issue for this can be found [here](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4481)